# C#: components cannot show on Windows Form

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0

I have created an empty project. after that, I added new items is Windows Form and add some component such as button or textbox in Design View.

In main file, I use this code:

```
SimpleForm form = new SimpleForm(); // SimpleForm is my class
form.Show();
```

But, when I run, C# generate a form but I cannot see textbox nor button. I just see blank area where I put those components. As picture below, the white area is my button, but I don't know why this button cannot show. I think maybe some problem, and those components cannot draw on the form.

[image]

Please help me this error.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "the main file" you mean your main method (the entry point) - try this code instead:

```
Application.EnableVisualStyles();
Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
Application.Run(new SimpleForm());
```

If not you really need to post more of your code to get a reasonable answer.

Comment: ah. thanks, it runs now. can you tell me why we must do this. thanks :)

Comment: Application.Run starts a message loop on the supplied form which becomes the main form for the app.  Without calling that, I believe the app just shows the form and exits.  Not very useful.